# Property 'next' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter' in WebDataRocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, eventemitter, webdatarocks

While integrating the WebDataRocks in angular for pivot table, I am getting the error

> Property 'next' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter<CellData>'

Here is my code,

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as WebDataRocks from 'webdatarocks';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-wbr-pivot',
    template: `<div><div class='wbr-ng-wrapper'></div></div>`
})
export class WebdatarocksComponent implements OnInit{
    // params
    @Input() toolbar: boolean;
    @Input() width: string | number;
    @Input() height: string | number;
    @Input() report: WebDataRocks.Report | string;
    @Input() global: WebDataRocks.Report;
    @Input() customizeCell: (cell: WebDataRocks.CellBuilder, data: WebDataRocks.CellData) => void;
    // events
    @Output() cellclick: EventEmitter<WebDataRocks.CellData> = new EventEmitter();
    
    // api
    public webDataRocks: WebDataRocks.Pivot;
    // private
    private root: HTMLElement;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {  }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.root = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
      this.webDataRocks = new WebDataRocks({
          container: this.root.getElementsByClassName('wbr-ng-wrapper')[0],
          width: this.width,
          height: this.height,
          toolbar: this.toolbar,
          report: this.report,
          global: this.global,
          customizeCell: this.customizeCell,
          cellclick: (cell: WebDataRocks.CellData) => this.cellclick.next(cell)
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce this with the same code on my side. Have you changed anything else in the sample project perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

EventEmitter's `next` method is deprecated in favor of `emit`

```
this.cellclick.emit(cell)
```